# Measuring the similarity of two waveforms

Tags: correlation, measurement

I have two approximately sine truncated waveforms of different amplitudes and I want a numerical measure of how similar they are to each other. I am sending a sonic pulse train whose multiple reflections I am receiving. I want to know which of those reflections most closely correlate with each other in terms of wave shape.
Any standard methods?

Comment: Could you elaborate more and provide examples? Otherwise there is plenty of techniques that can be applied to this particular problem. The more specific question, the better answers you will get.

Comment: As your question already suggests, why not calculate the auto-correlation for the received signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the term (and process) I am looking for is "[autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation)".